# Starting worker process failed - Azure Timer Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have a Net 5 Azure function app that was running fine with two queue trigger functions but as soon as I added a timer function, I get theses two errors:

> Starting worker process failed. The operation has timed out.

This repeats 3 times then shuts down the host.

For testing purposes, I added the timer function and left the default azure template; only modified the schedule. I've been able create a new function app that only has one timer trigger function and run it without any issues.

Any ideas on why the combination of queue trigger functions and timer trigger functions within the same Net 5 function app would be causing dotnet-worker issues?

Comment: I would recommend you open an issue on Github and it seems to be a problem with Azure Functions on Azure

Comment: Are you using the right package? For .Net 5, the `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer` package should be referenced.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I've got the same problem

Comment: Nope... I have been following https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/434 but a solution has not been found yet.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround for me was to clear the blob service in the AzureStorageEmulator.exe, but still waiting for a definitely solution.

[image]